# apply class based on props on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, classname

So, using react, I'm checking my props on click and aplying, or not, a class to my button based on those props. The issue is that I need to make that verification on render. Im thinking about a method that runs on render (selectedThumbnails ?) but Im not quite sure how to deal with the verification.

Here is my component:

```
class Thumbnail extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    selectedThumbnails = () => {
        console.log(this.props.selectedThumbnails()
    }

    render() {

        return (

            this.selectedThumbnails(),

            <div onClick={() => this.props.escolheTextura(this.props.textures)}
                 className={this.props.thumbnailsAtives.some(thumbnail => thumbnail === this.props.textures) ? "button is-primary thumbnail" : "button thumbnail"}>
                <Tooltip title={this.props.textureName}>
                <span>
                    <figure className={"image is-32x32"}>
                        <img src={this.props.textures.urlImage}/>
                    </figure>
                </span>
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

My onclick will apply the class "button is-primary thumbnail" to the button/buttons if there are some buttons in the array thumbnailsAtivas as in the "this.props.textures". I need to check this also on render, like in onLoad or so but I dont know how to apply a class with onLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thumbnail extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          selectedThumbnail:null
        }
    }

    thumblick = (thumb) => {
     this.setState({selectedThumbnail:thumb })
    }


    render() {

        return (


            <div onClick={() => this.thumblick(this.props.textures) }
                 className={this.state.selectedThumbnail === this.props.textures) ? "button is-primary thumbnail" : "button thumbnail"}>
                <Tooltip title={this.props.textureName}>
                <span>
                    <figure className={"image is-32x32"}>
                        <img src={this.props.textures.urlImage}/>
                    </figure>
                </span>
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
        )
    }
   };
```

First define empty state variable which will hold the selected image.
On click should set the state to the current selected thumbnail image.Changing state causes a rerender, this time it will compare through every thumb image with the selected thumb image stored in the state.
That time it will apply the class to the button

Comment: thanks for the answer but that doesnt solve my problem. I already have an array of thumbnails selected when the app runs, I just need to apply the class based on them and, what I understand so far from your help, I've got none thumbnail selected. Also, I need this to get the props checked on render not on click, in the 1st time